# How to Mock and test this Inner static class

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I am new to Mockito and PowerMock and am really having troubles in getting this one. This is pretty much situation I have:

```
class A {

  static class B {

    public class B(Object1 o1, Object2 o2) {
        setInSuperClass(o1); // this is private method...
        doSomethingWithInnerClass (new Object3() {

            @Override
            public void retreat() {
                someVar = new Object5(o2);   // someVar is from   superclass and is private, I know I can get it with PowerMock
            }

            @Override
            public boolean doSomething(){
                return true; 
            }

        })

    }
  }
}
```

I guess this would do the job for first method.... maybe I can also verify that some object is set in superclass and is not null any more, and that would be fine ?

```
    @Mock
    Object1 o1;

    @Mock
    Object2 o2;

    public void test() {
         B b = new B(o1, o2);
         PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(b).invoke("setInSuperClass", 1 , o1);
    }
```

but how to best test  doSomethingWithInnerClass ??? I mean, I know I can verify that it was called....but this anonymous class argument I would like to test.
I appreciate advices,
Thanx

Comment: The code of your class doesn't compile.

Comment: @JBNizet, I do not have access to code now, yes there might be some typoes , but this is a generic description of the issue

Comment: Since you owner of class I would move static inner to another class in subpackage. As well I don't see value to test that private method was called.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to redirect your thinking. For example, instead of verifying that `setInSuperClass` is called using Powermock, you should verify the result of the call. Is there a field that is set? Is there a getter on this field? Is there some other behavior that is driven by this field that could be verified?

The same is true of `doSomethingWithInnerClass`. A method call that doesn't DO anything might as well not be there. There must be a result of the call. Either some output, call to another method / class or side-effect. Verify the result.

If this is truly impossible, you might need to create a subclass of the inner class for testing. This subclass would override the method being called by the method under test.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be verifying that a private variable gets set.  You should be verifying whatever effect that has on the subsequent behaviour of the object.  So do what you need to do in order to run your `retreat` method, but then call some other method on the enclosing object, that uses the value of that private variable.

If there's no way to tell, from the enclosing object, that the variable has been set, then that suggests to me that the variable itself isn't actually needed.